# Silverstripe event calendar (MonthJumper): showing months in German don't work

Tags: php, calendar, silverstripe, setlocale

I have a problem with the month names in MonthJumper in the Silverstripe Event Calendar. I want the months to display in German. I tried the following code in my _config.php:

```
 i18n :: set_locale ('en_US');
 setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE @ euro', 'en_US.UTF-8', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge', 'eng');
 setlocale (LC_TIME, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

This works perfectly in my local version of the website, but on the live server it does not do anything..the months are still displayed in English. Is this a server problem? What can I do to change this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is the second Silverstripe question you've asked in the past half hour. Something tells me you haven't been reading the docs. Is there any truth to that? Please also check the time and locale settings on the server and compare against your local machine. If there are discrepancies then PHP can produce different results. setLocale() sets the locale to whatever setlocale on the server or OS does, well the return value at least, so you might want to check that.

Comment: thank you for your quick answers. @ 3dgoo: yes I have called ?flush=all? ...I have now send my problem to my webhoster.

Answer (score 0):

I used this Module to accomplish German Dates

https://github.com/richardsjoqvist/silverstripe-localdate

This should help you too

Comment: Thank you! I will try this on my next projects. For now my webhoster  changed some server settings so now everything works like expected.